# Reader Monad clarification

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

I am trying to make sense of the reader monad but can't seem to grasp what bind (>>=) does in this monad.

Here's the implementation I am analyzing:

```
newtype Reader e a = Reader { runReader :: (e -> a) }

instance Monad (Reader e) where 
    return a         = Reader $ \e -> a 
    (Reader r) >>= f = Reader $ \e -> runReader (f (r e)) e
```

1. My first question is, why is Reader partially applied on the left
   hand side of bind? `(Reader r)` instead of `(Reader r a)`.
2. What goes on in this part of the definition: `(f (r e))`, what is it's purpose?

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My first question is, why is Reader partially applied on the left hand side of bind? `(Reader r)` instead of `(Reader r a)`.

It isn’t. That use of `Reader` is fully saturated, as it must be. However, I can understand your confusion… remember that in Haskell, types and values are in different namespaces, and defining a datatype with `data` or `newtype` brings new names into scope in both namespaces. For example, consider the following declaration:

```
data Foo = Bar | Baz
```

This definition binds three names, `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`. However, the part on the left-hand side of the equals sign is bound in the type namespace, since `Foo` is a type, and the constructors on the right hand side are bound in the value namespace, since `Bar` and `Baz` are essentially values.

All of these things have types as well, which can be helpful to visualize. `Foo` has a *kind*, which is essentially the “type of a type-level thing”, and `Bar` and `Baz` both have a type. These types can be written as follows:

```
Foo :: *
Bar :: Foo
Baz :: Foo
```

…where `*` is the kind of types.

Now, consider a slightly more complicated definition:

```
data Foo a = Bar Integer String | Baz a
```

Once again, this definition binds three names: `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`. Once again, `Foo` is in the type namespace and `Bar` and `Baz` are in the value namespace. Their types, however, are more elaborate:

```
Foo :: * -> *
Bar :: Integer -> String -> Foo a
Baz :: a -> Foo a
```

Here, `Foo` is a type constructor, so it’s essentially a type-level function that accepts a type (`*`) as an argument. Meanwhile, `Bar` and `Baz` are value-level functions that accept various values as arguments.

Now, return to the definition of `Reader`. Avoiding record syntax for a moment, we can reformulate it as follows:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader (r -> a)
```

This binds one name in the type namespace and one name in the value namespace, but the confusing part is that they’re both named `Reader`! This is totally allowed in Haskell, though, since the namespaces are separate. Each `Reader` has a kind/type in this case, too:

```
Reader :: * -> * -> *
Reader :: (r -> a) -> Reader r a
```

Note that the type-level `Reader` takes two arguments, but the value-level `Reader` only takes one. When you pattern-match against a value, you are using the value-level constructor (since you’re deconstructing a value that was built up using that same constructor), and the value only contains one value (as it must, since `Reader` is a `newtype`), so the pattern only binds a single variable.

---

> What goes on in this part of the definition: `(f (r e))`, what is it's purpose?

`Reader` is essentially a mechanism for composing a lot of functions that all take the same argument. It’s a way to avoid having to thread a value around everywhere, since the various instances will do the plumbing automatically.

To understand the definition of `>>=` for `Reader`, let’s specialize the type of `>>=` to `Reader`:

```
(>>=) :: Reader r a -> (a -> Reader r b) -> Reader r b
```

For the purpose of clarity, we can also expand `Reader r a` to `r -> a`, just to get a better intuition for what the type actually *means*:

```
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
```

Let’s also name the arguments here for the purpose of discussion:

```
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
(>>=)    f           g             =  ...
```

Let’s think about this for a moment. We are given two functions, `f` and `g`, and we are expected to produce a function that produces a value of type `b` from a value of type `a`. We only have *one* way to produce a `b`, and that’s by calling `g`. But in order to call `g`, we have to have an `a`, and we only have one way to get an `a`: call `f`! We *can* call `f`, since it only needs an `r`, which we already have, so we can start attaching the functions together to produce the `b` we need.

This is a little confusing, so it might help to see this flow of values visually:

```
          +------------+
          | input :: r |
          +------------+
             |       |
             v       |
+--------------+     |
| f input :: a |     |
+--------------+     |
       |             |
       v             v
  +------------------------+
  | g (f input) input :: b |
  +------------------------+
```

In Haskell, this looks like this:

```
f >>= g = \input -> g (f input) input
```

…or, renaming things a little to match the definition in your question:

```
r >>= f = \e -> f (r e) e
```

Now, we need to reintroduce some wrapping and unwrapping, since the real definition is on the `Reader` type, not `(->)` directly. This means we need to add some uses of the `Reader` wrapper and the `runReader` unwrapper, but otherwise the definition is the same:

```
Reader r >>= f = Reader (\e -> runReader (f (r e)) e)
```

At this point, you can check your intuition: `Reader` is a way to thread a value around between a lot of functions, and here we’re composing two functions, `r` and `f`. Therefore, we should need to pass the value in twice, which we do: there are two uses of `e` in the above definition.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your function, `Monad` is class over types of *kind* `* -> *`.

- `[Int] :: *` = list of integers
- `[] :: * -> *` = list
- `Reader e a :: *` = reader with environment e resulting in a
- `Reader e :: * -> *` = reader with environment e
- `Reader :: * -> * -> *` = reader

We are lousy when we say *`Reader` has a monad instance*, when we mean
*`Reader` with any environment has a monad instance*.

(Similarly, `Writer w` is a `Monad` when `w` is a `Monoid`, `Writer` isn't a
`Monad`).

---

To answer your second question, it's easier to think in terms of
the `Reader e a` as the same as function `e -> a`.

Function has the same monad definition, but without `newtype` wrappers and
unwrappers. Think `Reader = (->)`:

```
instance Monad ((->) e) where
    return x = \_ -> x -- alternatively, return = const !
    r >>= f  = \e -> f (r e) e
```

Yet, the `join` definition is probably most insightful:

```
join :: Reader e (Reader e a) -> Reader e a
```

But with bare function:

```
join :: (e -> e -> a) -> (e -> a)
join f e = f e e
```

And if we write it for `Reader` we have to add `runReader` and `Reader` in
right places (and move variable binding to the lambda on RHS):

```
join f = Reader $ \e -> runReader (runReader f e) e
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no partial application. `Reader` is a `newtype` definition that 'wraps' exactly *one* value (`runReader`), which is a function of the type `e -> a`. So, `Reader r` just pattern-matches the function out of the `Reader` wrapper. `r` is bound to the function of type `e -> a`.
2. `f` is a function, as is `r`. `r e` invokes the function `r` with the value `e`, and then `f` is invoked with the result of that function call.